# adding row in section with button

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview. Tableview has 6 sections and each section has some rows.on every section there is a button.once I tap the button alert will come and the I can give  a new rowname.on tapping ok button of the alert a new row will be added.

Comment: Please provide us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more item to the collection you are using to store the data rows (for example, you can be using a `NSArray`), and then call:

```
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

On your table view.

With the information you have provided this is the best I can tell you.

Comment: And what is the problem? If you have updated the collection, the row shoudl appear

Comment: row is only getting added in the first section,no matter for which section i have tapped the button.

Comment: UITextField *rowTextTF=[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

Comment: if (section_number==0)
        {
            [_socialdata addObject:rowTextTF.text];
            [_socialdata retain];
        }
        else if (section_number== 1)
        {
            [_auctiondata addObject:rowTextTF.text];
            [_auctiondata retain];
        }
        else if (section_number== 2)
        {
            [_ecommercedata addObject:rowTextTF.text];
            [_ecommercedata retain];
            
        }

Comment: [_websitesList reloadData];

Comment: Did you fix it? In case you didnt, please paste your code in the main question. IF you did, please accept the answer